# Запись значения из <input type='text'> в переменную и добавление нового значения

Tags: javascript, html, twig

У меня есть таблица, при нажатии на баттон я должен записать в переменные значения, которые записаны в input.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Add").bind("click", function(event) {
      const question = ? ? ;
      const answer1 = ? ? ;
      $.ajax({
          url: "questionedit/Add",
          type: "GET",
          data: ({
            Question:
              ...
          }),
          success: /*и тут ещё как - то добавить новое значение из БД*/
        }
      })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" required name="QuestionName"></td>
    <td><input type="text" required name="1stAnswer"></td>
    <td><input type="text" required name="2stAnswer"></td>
    <td><input type="text" required name="3stAnswer"></td>
    <td><input type="text" required name="4stAnswer"></td>
    <td><button id="Add" type="submit">Add question</button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Думал записать через

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var add = document.getElementById('Add');

add.onclick = function (){
var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');
 var forGet = {};
   for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
         var z = input[i].name;
        forGet[z] = input[i].value;
    }
    console.log(forGet)

}
```