# Как вывести новые данные, дополненные AJAX запросом

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, twig

У меня есть функции, которые при нажатии передают AJAX запрос и добавляют значения в бд, которые записаны в Input. Что мне прописать в Success, чтоб эти значения без перезагрузки заносились в мою базу данных.
Вот сам запрос.

```
$(document).ready (function (){
             $("#Add").bind("click",function () {
                 input = document.getElementsByClassName('inputQuestion');
                 tryAnswer=document.getElementsByClassName('radioButton');
                 forGet = {};
                 for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                     z = input[i].name;
                     forGet[z] = input[i].value;
                 }

                 trueAns=0;

                 for (i=0; i<tryAnswer.length;i++) {
                     if (tryAnswer[i].checked) {
                         trueAns=tryAnswer[i].value;
                     }
                 }
                 $.ajax({
                     url: "questionedit/add",
                     type: "GET",
                     data: ({
                         questions: forGet['QuestionName'],
                         answer1:forGet['1stAnswer'],
                         answer2:forGet['2stAnswer'],
                         answer3:forGet['3stAnswer'],
                         answer4:forGet['4stAnswer'],
                         trueAnswer:trueAns
                     }),
                     success:
                 })
             })
         });
```

А вот и вёрстка:

```
</body>
<div>
    <table class="questionTable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="RedWord">Question</th>
            <th>1st variant</th>
            <th>2st variant</th>
            <th>3st variant</th>
            <th>4st variant</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="inputQuestion" placeholder="Question" required name="QuestionName"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="inputQuestion" placeholder="Answer" required name="1stAnswer" ><input type="radio" name="1" value="1" class="radioButton"> </td>
            <td><input type="text" class="inputQuestion" placeholder="Answer" required name="2stAnswer" ><input type="radio" name="1" value="2" class="radioButton"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="inputQuestion" placeholder="Answer" required name="3stAnswer" ><input type="radio" name="1" value="3" class="radioButton"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="inputQuestion" placeholder="Answer" required name="4stAnswer"><input type="radio" name="1"  value="4" class="radioButton"></td>
            <td><button id="Add" type="submit">Add question</button></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>

        {% for question in questions %}
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ question.name_of_question }}</td>
                {% for answer in answers %}
                    {% if answer.Question_id.id==question.id %}
                        {% if answer.right_answer==1 %}
                        <td>{{ answer.name_of_answer }}<input type="radio" checked name="{{ question.id }}" id="{{ answer.Id }}"></td>
                        {% else%}
                            <td>{{ answer.name_of_answer }}<input type="radio" name="{{ question.id }}" id="{{ answer.Id }}"></td>
                    {%endif%}
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                <td><button data-index={{ question.id }} class="quetions" type="button">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: В каком смысле? Они же и так в бд заносятся

Comment: @Михаил, да. Но чтоб это отобразилось у меня на странице в таблице, то её нужно обновить. А как добавить без обновления?

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич, портите карму себе. Я вижу у Вас с вой код, который писал в ответе на предыдущий  Ваш вопрос.  Вы воспользовались им, но не приняли ответ. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743667/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-input-type-text-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/743701#743701

Comment: Вы хотите вывести бд в таблицу...?

Comment: @Дмытрык прошу прощение. Спасибо большое. Забыл принять.

Comment: @Михаил у меня есть таблица, там значения из БД. И верхняя строчка это добавить значение. 5 input. Когда я нажимаю на баттон, то все значения, что в инпутах, они записывают бд, но самого отображение таблицы не выводит новые значения. Оно выведет если только перезагрузить страницу. А как сделать, чтоб оно без перезагрузки выводило

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич, а сервер возвращает ответ после получения AJAX-запроса?

Comment: @Дмытрык да, но если я перекинусь или приму что-то из ответа, то произойдёт обновления, насколько я понимаю. Тут надо по средствам JS каким-то образом вписать

Comment: Ajax-запрос для того и отправляется, чтобы получить ответ сервера без перезагрузки

Comment: а как тогда переключиться на ответ?

Comment: Есть два варианта... 1- получаете data и всё остальное выполняет уже в success. Или ставите в запросе async:false, тогда можно будет в success изменять значения внешних переменных